# Could not open input file: application.php Symfony CLI

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

i am trying to **Create a basic Command** in Symfony.

So i am following this the cookbook in [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#creating-a-basic-command).

But where it says Test the new console command by running the following

```
$ php application.php demo:greet Fabien
```

there i am always getting an error, says ---

> Could not open input file: application.php

i have create `**GreetCommand.php**` file and copy that exact php commands. and also create a **application.php** file where i follow the instruction.

i have put those two files in the same directory/folder.

What i am doing wrong and why i am getting that error.

Here is code for `**GreetCommand.php**` ---

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GreetCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('demo:greet')
            ->setDescription('Greet someone')
            ->addArgument(
                'name',
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'Who do you want to greet?'
            )
            ->addOption(
               'yell',
               null,
               InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
               'If set, the task will yell in uppercase letters'
            )
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');
        if ($name) {
            $text = 'Hello '.$name;
        } else {
            $text = 'Hello';
        }

        if ($input->getOption('yell')) {
            $text = strtoupper($text);
        }

        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

here is the code for **application.php** ---

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// application.php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use AppBundle\Command\GreetCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new GreetCommand());
$application->run();
```

Comment: Try: php ./application.php demo:greet Fabien  And of course make sure you are in the same directory as your files.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting suggests that the path to `application.php` is not valid. The same error is reproducible  by invoking PHP on a non-existant file:

```
$ php doesnotexist.php
```

outputs:

> Could not open input file: doesnotexist.php

---

The documentation you [linked to](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#creating-a-basic-command) refers to Symfony's console *component*, but based on your code snippet, you appear to be using the entire Symfony *framework*. The distinction is important as components are expected to be functional independently from the rest of the framework which means the implementation may differ slightly when using the rest of the framework.

I suspect this cookbook article will be much more helpful: [How to Create a Console Command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html)